# How to make a card widget touchable in Flutter?

Tags: dart, widget, flutter

I am currently making an app with lists of a **Card** widgets. This is a code snippet:

```
new GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          showAlert(); 
        //pops up an AlertDialog
        },
        child: new Card(child: new Text("Hello"))
)
```

Is it possible to make the Card widget touchable, so **the user can feel/see that the card is (long)tapped?** I am searching for an 'InkWell-something result'.

*Edit:* I want to have a splash effect on my Card widgets when I longpress them.
An example of the splash effect that I mean is given in the following GIF:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you expect?

Comment: I added a little example.

Comment: Pretty weird that you said the word "InkWell" in your question and expected the InkWell widget as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
return Card(
    child: InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  onLongPress: () {}
  child: Container(),
));
```

Comment: Looks like the answer was not that difficult! Thank you!